# Pass a parameter from an ExpressJs request to another file in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

First of all thank you and please keep in mind that I'm quite new to Node.

I'm trying to create a fake profiles json creator (for development purposes) and came across fakerJs. What I did so far is:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')

const User = require('./api/user')

const app = express();
const port = 4000

app.get('/user/:times', (req, res) => {
    res.json(User)
});



app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server Starts at ${port}`)
})
```

So, this requires the file **user.js**:

```
const faker = require('faker')

var _name = faker.name.findName();

var _eventTime = faker.date.future();

var User = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var newUser = {
        type: "selling",
        speaker: _name,
        image: faker.name.firstName(),
        title: faker.commerce.productName(),
        description: faker.hacker.phrase(),
        time: _eventTime,
        duration: 5,
        speakerInfo: [
            {
                name: _name,
                bio: faker.lorem.sentences(),
                twitter: null,
                github: null,
                company: null   
            }       
        ],
        eventStart: _eventTime,
        eventEnd: _eventTime,
        eventDuration: 5,
        productImage: [
            faker.image.technics(),
            faker.image.technics()
        ],
        avatarUrl: faker.image.people()
    }
    User.push(newUser);
}

module.exports = User
```

As you could image, what I want is to call /api/user/10 and that will replace the number 5 in the for loop for that amount.

I tried different options (and also read many other similar questions):
- Moved the functionality to the server.js and get it as req.params.times
- Send it to the user.js file by using app.get('/user/:times', Users.createUser(10), (req,res) => { ... }

What am I doing wrong and what's the right way to do this?

Note: I do know that right now I´m not passing the parameter time to the loop and I'm looping 5 times to it. I do not pass time as I do not know how to do it, that's actually my question.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your not passing the number :times to user nore is the 5 in your loop a variable also your exporting an array that won't ever change even if you change what i just mentioned because it is getting​ created when you do the require() also your faker code is out side your loop so you will always get the same data(not 100% on this because I've never used that)

Comment: Ok, I guess I should add those to the code to clarify... I do know that right now I´m using an int (5) and that will return 5 times (and yeah, I know it will loop 5 times because it goes from 0 to 4.

In my code I´m not passing :times to the user.js file... because that´s actually my question. I do not know how to do it.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params

Comment: Learn how to make modules. Your user file should be exporting a function that returns a arry of users that is created based on the parameter passed to it.

Comment: Also i like to use this websites api for creating fake users randomuser.me if you know how to use request in node it's pretty good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass time, just let the function User to handle the request and response.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')

const user = require('./api/user')

const app = express();
const port = 4000

app.get('/user/:times', user);        

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server Starts at ${port}`)
});
```

In this module, a handler function is exported.

**user.js:**

```
const faker = require('faker')

var _name = faker.name.findName();

var _eventTime = faker.date.future();

var User = function(req, res) {
  var users = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < +req.params.times; i++) {
    var newUser = {
        type: "selling",
        speaker: _name,
        image: faker.name.firstName(),
        title: faker.commerce.productName(),
        description: faker.hacker.phrase(),
        time: _eventTime,
        duration: 5,
        speakerInfo: [
            {
                name: _name,
                bio: faker.lorem.sentences(),
                twitter: null,
                github: null,
                company: null   
            }       
        ],
        eventStart: _eventTime,
        eventEnd: _eventTime,
        eventDuration: 5,
        productImage: [
            faker.image.technics(),
            faker.image.technics()
        ],
        avatarUrl: faker.image.people()
    }
    users.push(newUser);
  }
  res.json(users);
}

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: This solves the problem! I see now. I must move the res.json to the ¨module¨and simply call it (the module) within the .get.

Comment: No he did route separation here.

Comment: Still doesn't explain to you why it works. Nore that it's completely different to what you were trying to achieve.